# Freeing upcasted structs in C, how safe it is?

Tags: c, memory, polymorphism

I'm doing some polymorphic C code and i wonder if both of memory freeing functions presented bellow, will work correctly. I am pretty sure that `void free_casted_parent(Parent* parent)` is correct, but i started wondering if this specialization inside is necessary?

```
typedef enum {
    CHILD_TYPE_1,
    CHILD_TYPE_2,
} Kind;

typedef struct {
    Kind kind;
} Parent;

typedef struct {
    Kind kind;
    int value;
} ChildType1;

typedef struct {
    Kind kind;
    float other_value;
} ChildType2;


void free_parent(Parent* parent) {
    free(parent);
}

void free_casted_parent(Parent* parent) {
    switch (parent->kind) {
        case CHILD_TYPE_1:
            free((ChildType1*) parent);
            break;
        case CHILD_TYPE_2:
            free((ChildType2*) parent);
            break;
    }
}

int main() { 
    ChildType1* ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(ChildType1));
    ChildType2* ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(ChildType2));

    // do some stuff with both variants of parent
    
    free_parent((Parent*) ptr1);
    free_casted_parent((Parent*) ptr2);

    return 0;
}
```

If the `free_casted_parent(Parent* parent)` is not correct, how would that differ from freeing heap allocated array of values? In both cases we pass valid address without specifying exact size

Comment: Remember that [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) expects a `void *` pointer. I.e. it's a pointer to an object without any knowledge of its actual type. As long as you have a pointer to something returned by `malloc` (or its family) then it can be passed to `free`. Once `free` is called the type is lost.

Comment: Related: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858) The answer is "no", partly because `void *` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type (except pointers to functions). The same is true in reverse, any pointer (except pointers to functions) can be implicitly converted to `void *`. You should not cast the pointers you pass to `free`, just as you should not cast the pointers that `malloc` returns.

Comment: It's impossible to comment on this without knowing how you allocated memory in the first place. Also there's nothing called "upcasted" in C - there are only correct casts and incorrect casts. A struct may be cast to a pointer to it's first member. But a struct may not get casted to another struct which happens to have a similar first member, with exception of a special oddball rule known as "common initial sequence" (long story).

Comment: Prefer passing a variable opposed to a type to sizeof, i.e. `malloc(sizeof *ptr1);`.

Comment: @Lundin Common initial sequences [only apply to unions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p6):  "if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible."  Offhand, I believe that makes casting pointers like the OP is doing undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Casting between pointers types is not undefined behavior except for alignment issues or casting between pointers to objects and pointers to functions. Using the pointers, notably to access memory, is an issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know that, but the union in the context of that oddball rule is just there to serve as a converter - it just need to sit in the same translation unit as the two structs but you don't actually have to create an instance of it. And like I said, it's a long story, because you cannot rely on any existing compiler to implement this properly even today, afaik.

Comment: "do some stuff with both variants of parent"  Eeh? What does this even mean? There is no `Parent` instance anywhere in your code.

Comment: Please accept the best answer so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the pointer conversions in the code shown are defined by C 2018 6.3.2.3 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer…

Since the pointers are allocated with `malloc`, which provides memory suitably addressed for any fundamental type, the second sentence of the above does not apply, and the behavior is defined. That said, the pointer conversions in the `free` calls are useless as a call to `free` implicitly converts the argument to `void *`, making `free((ChildType1*) parent);` equivalent to `free((void *) parent);` or `free(parent);`.

The only code shown that raises an issue of undefined behavior is `switch (parent->kind)`. (There could be issues in the code not shown in `// do some stuff with both variants of parent`.) This accesses memory using the type `Parent`, but we do not know what the effective type of the memory is, because the effective type of dynamically allocated memory depends on the type used to store values to the memory, and that code is not shown. Presumably `ChildType1` or `ChildType2` was used, in which case this access likely violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7 and thus has undefined behavior.

Comment: We can't really answer without knowing the effective type and the allocation of all types involved. Speculating about what code which isn't posted might do isn't helpful - prompt the OP to post said code instead.

Comment: @Lundin: The allocation is shown; `malloc` calls are shown in the code. And we can answer without knowing the effective type by answering conditionally depending on the effective type, which this answer does. Further, it is a reasonable presumption that the effective type is in at least some instances one of the two “child” types, as that is both a clear purpose of the code and given in the question (“polymorphic”).

Comment: `parent->kind` does *not* access memory using the type `Parent`, it accesses it with the type `Kind`. That matches the effective type of `Kind` presumably stored in the field with an assignment like `ptr1->kind =`... via a ChildType ptr

Comment: @ChrisDodd: For the purpose of interpreting the aliasing rule, `parent->kind` accesses the structure that `parent` points to. If it did not, then a compiler could not assume that pointers `p` and `q` to `struct point { double x, y; }` and `struct complex { double real, imaginary; }` pointed to different objects when used as `p->x` and `q->real`, but this is a purpose of the aliasing rule.

Comment: The compiler can't assume that, as any other compilation unit might contain a `union` that contains both a `struct point` and a `struct complex`.  Such a compilation unit might not even exist yet, but could be created in the future and linked with this code.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That reasoning would almost entirely nullify the aliasing rule, as any object accessed by pointer could be pointing to some union member. The C standard is imperfect in its specification of how aliasing and accesses are to be interpreted for aggregates and unions, but pointers to two different types are intended to point to different objects except for the cases enumerated in the aliasing rule.

Comment: There are conflicting intentions behind the aliasing rules.  Some want to codify what existing code tends to assume while others want to enable improved optimzation.  The result is conflcting rules that don't always work together well.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: C 2018 6.5.2.3 9 specifically addresses this in an example. Its second code fragment, which it says is invalid, has code in which `p1` and `p2` are pointers to two members of the same union, having been passed as such by their caller, and their types are pointers to two structures that are identically declared except for their tags. So, in this example, it is clear that the fact that `p1->m` and `p2->m` are the same type (`int`) is insufficient to satisfy the aliasing rule. The fact `*p1` and `*p2` are different types means the rule is violated.

Answer (score 1):

The `free()` will work correctly but overly complicated opposed to:

```
free(ptr1);
free(ptr2);
```

Any object pointer can be converted to/from a `void *` which is what `free()` operates on.

The implicit cast to `Parent *` from the two unrelated types `ChildType1 *` or `ChildType2 *` in the call to `free_casted_parent()` is problematic per 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the
> following types:89)
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object [...]

You are missing a `#include <stdlib.h>`.

`malloc()` returns NULL (on error) which will cause `parent->` to segfault.  You want to check for that.

You want want to consider two alternative designs:

1. Use a regular tagged union:

```
typedef struct  {
  Kind kind;
  union {
    int value;
    float other_value;
  };
} ChildType;
```

2. If you don't need the run-time polymorphic behavior leave out the tag and handle each type accordingly (possible using a macro to generate type specific functions that are otherwise identical).  As you probably have `n` of these children you save `n * size(Kind)` plus potentially padding in your `struct`s.

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} ChildType1;

typedef struct {
    float value;
} ChildType2;
```

If you have more than 1 member in your child types you find that storing your data as a struct of arrays will be a faster at run-time, and depending on the types of your members lead to less padding:

```
typedef struct {
   int *values;
} ChildType1;

// ...

ChildType1 childtype1;
childtype1.values = malloc((sizeof *childtype1.values) * 42)
```

Comment: “it will work correctly” cannot be asserted without qualification because `parent->kind` accesses memory using the type `Parent` but the memory was presumably stored in the unshown `// do some stuff with both variants of parent` code using types of `ChildType1` or `ChildType2`. Those stores would give the memory an effective type of `ChildType1` or `ChildType2`, so the access using the `Parent` type would violate the aliasing rules in 6.5 7, making the behavior of the program not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Added more context and your reference as to why the implicit cast int he function call is problematic.  Let me know if I am still missing something.